# Inverting OpAmp non-symmetric output

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've got the attached circuit and layout setup - basic signal conditioning going into an ADC. First we buffer the signal with a unity gain follower. I can verify with the scope that the output at TP2 matches the input as expected. The second stage (single dual op-amp chip LM358) is inverting with a gain of -0.37 to attenuate this to +/- 3.7V for the ADC. (Note that R17 is just an extra footprint and is not populated.) In practice the output of this stage goes to about +3.7V when the input is -10V as expected, but as the input goes up to +10V the output never goes much below about -1V. This non-symmetric behavior has me puzzled as it simulates out correctly in circuit lab and LTSpice. I've also attached the layout for those curious. I've checked it, the pinout of the part, that correct values are populated, and even swapped the Op-Amp. What blatantly obvious thing am I missing here?

Note TP1 and TP11 are on the same net, the layout just worked out with TP11 here.
[image: Schematic]
[image: PCB Layout]

Update per solution. Simulation shows this to provide basically 0-2V out to the ADC.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single supply ADC that cannot accept inputs outside supply rails +/-0.3V.

So you are overdriving the ESD protection diodes ( not good) which are Schottky at -1V.  which can cause shoot-thru latchup currents and damage IC from heat.

> Abs. Max= GND – 0.3.

You cannot get +/- 4.096 V input with a 3.3V supply.

You can use 3.3V supply , but you have to choose +/-2.096V range and change gain to   for your +/- 10V input signal and add a negative offset  to scaling OpAmp In-.

[image]

Input -10.00V to + 10.00V
Output 0.000V to 2.000V +/- component tolerance stack error.
These values are available in 0.1%,0.05%,0.02% and 0.01%.

Comment: Let me clarify, the measurement I'm taking is with a scope at test point 3.

Comment: Yes I know that. See footnote 1 in Input range specs

Comment: It’s a common oversight, you won’t make again.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the post to show my solution. Simulation shows it producing about 0-2V out to the ADC which should fulfill all of the requirements.

Comment: That's good.  I don't know your total error budget from component tolerances , CM noise and supply accuracy, but  another way, allows the choice of lower error tolerance parts, < 0.1%

Comment: Spinning the PCB I'd do that for sure, but in an effort to salvage these I can use the extra footprint and move ahead. Thanks for the better alternative though - should I respin, I'll do that for sure!

Comment: It's a good idea to have an error budget before you start your next design.

Answer (score 1):

The a to d converter can not handle inputs less than it’s ground terminal. You are forward biasing it’s input ESD protection with the negative drive of the op amp.